# Stretching sidewaysfigure to the max

Tags: graphics, rotating

I am experimenting with the sidewaysfigure as I need to have a graphic wider than the normal `\textwidth`. I tried `\paperwidth` but is it possible to stretch the figure to fill in e.g. 95% of the whole page?

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{...}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

in normal scape, the following does the trick:

```
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.95\paperwidth]{...}}
\end{center}
```

But with sideways it stretches only to textwidth anyhow.

Another question is, how do I avoid the pagestyle, meaning chapter title and pagenumbering on the page of the sideway? The following gets ignored.

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Help is highly appreciated, thank you

Caruso

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same for the rotated figure as in normal portrait layout. `sidewaysfigure` only rotates the figure and not the page, so the normal page distances are the same. If you use `\paperheight` in your command it works.

The `\thispagestyle{empty}` is not ignored, but I think it is on the wrong page. The environment `sidewaysfigure` is set on a separate page as a float and therefore `\thispagestyle{empty}` ends up where the code is given, and not on the float page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.95\paperheight,height=10em]{example-image}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

There are probably easier ways to do this than what is coming here. Since `sideways` is an environment that rotates the contents 90 degrees I understand the question now as you like a separate page with one centered picture that might be bigger than the text block. In my tests this does not work with sideways since it puts the contents on a line that does not stretch below the text block. So instead I rotate the picture with `\rotatebox` and put it inside a `\raisebox` where I set the height to `\baselinestretch`. That means its upper border is the same as the upper border for the text block. Then what is left up to the page border is `1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep`. That gives a way to center the picture vertically on the page. Then using the same horizontal centering as in the question gives the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%
\newcommand\bigsidewaysimg[3]{% {width}{height}{image file}
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth]{%
    \raisebox{%
      \dimexpr 1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\baselineskip
      -0.5\dimexpr 0pt+\paperheight-#2\relax\relax}[\baselineskip][0pt]{%
      \rotatebox{90}{%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{%
          \includegraphics[width=#2,height=#1]{#3}}}}
  }%
  \newpage}
%%%%%
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\bigsidewaysimg{0.9\paperwidth}{0.9\paperheight}{example-image-c}
\bigsidewaysimg{10cm}{10cm}{example-image-a}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic \paperheight works marvellous.
Any idea how to avoid the chapter title and pagenumbering on the page of the sideway?

Comment: I have updated with `\thispagestyle{empty}` inside the `sidewaysfigure`. That should remove header and footer.

Comment: sorry to bother, for some reason that doesn't work in the sideways environment.

Comment: Is it removing the page number or stretching the image that does not work in sideways?

Comment: @Caruso33 You are right, `\thispagestyle{empty}` does not work with `sidewaysfigure` since it behaves like a float on a separate page. I removed it again. And `sideways` is not on a separate page so it does not behave the same way.

Comment: @Caruso33 Hopefully the edit above can help.